# Prove $\frac{\mu}{L}=\frac{\frac{Q}{2}}{M}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, magnetic-moment

I was studying magnetism. I encountered a relation but with no proof. It was a statement. It says

> If for a body, charge and mass distribution is same then $$\frac{\mu}{L}=\frac{\frac{Q}{2}}{M}$$
> where $\mu$ is the magnetic moment of the body about an axis, $L$ is angular momentum of the body about the same axis, $M$ is the mass of the body and $Q$ is th charge evenly distributed on the body.

How to prove it$?$ I tried by taking some examples. I first took a rod, then a disc and then a shell. I found all of them with the help of integration (by taking an element and then integrating).

All of them follow this relation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider a point charge ($q$) of mass $m$ at $r$ revolving around an origin ($r=0$) with angular frequency $\omega$, the angular momentum is:

$$ L = \omega I $$

with

$$ I = mr^2 $$

Meanwhile, the magnetic moment is:

$$ \mu = \bar i A $$

where the area of orbit is:

$$ A = \pi r^2 $$

and the average current is:

$$ \bar i = \frac{q\omega}{2\pi} $$

so:

$$ \frac{\mu} L = \frac{\bar i A}{\omega I}$$
$$ \frac{\mu} L = \frac{ \frac{q\omega}{2\pi}\pi r^2}{\omega mr^2}$$
$$ \frac{\mu} L = \frac{q/2} m $$

Now just add particles up into any shape.

Comment: Thanks sir..I was having a hard time proving this